# What does .text actually do to a value?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I want to tell you that I am barely starting to learn Xcode and Swift and I am truly ignorant in these matters. Having said that, I would really appreciate it if you could explain this to me. I am watching a series of videos from a course on Xcode, and at some point of the video, the teacher wrote the following code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
     @IBOutlet weak var ageTextField: UITextField!
     @IBOutlet weak var resultLabel: UILabel!

     @IBAction func getAge(_ sender: Any) {
          if let age = ageTextField.text

     }
}
```

Why did he add that `.text` part to the text field? What is that `.text` telling Swift to do exactly? Isn't a Text Field already a text? Can I add `.text` to other things like a button or a label?

Comment: Command-click on `UITextField` and select *Jump to Definition*.  You'll see that `UITextField` is a class that inherits from `UIControl`.  It has many properties, one of which is `text` which is a `String?`.

Comment: This is very basic stuff, I would strongly suggest you take a step back and get a better grasp of the basics. Apple [has some great resources](https://www.apple.com/swift/), including an e-book that would be a good starting point to learn about object oriented programming with Swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being a `UITextField` doesn't mean you can access it's content when you type it only , but there are also a lot of properties for it like `attributedPlaceholder` , `tag` , `layer` , `frame` and many many more for per-kown purposes , and these properties are defined inside it , plus ones that it inherits form it's super classes following inheritance 1 of the backbones of any OOP , so according to that you have to write

```
let age = ageTextField.text
```

and here why the `if` because the text property is optional meaning that it can be nil , "" or any current content so you may do

```
let age = ageTextField.text

if age != nil  {
  then use age! // note ! means get the content of age as it's not nil anymore 
}
```

and this is equivalent to

```
if let age = ageTextField.text 
  then use age // here age is unwrapped as if let verfies that it has non-nil value 
}
```